# mongodb sort unpopulated subdocument

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, populate

I'm trying to sort unbinded subdocuments. This is the collection:

```
[
    {
        otherFields: {},
        visites: ["58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de4a", "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de49"]
    }
]
```

And this is the aggregate:

```
db.exps.aggregate([
    { "$match": {} },
    { "$project": { "visites": 1 } },
    { "$unwind": "$visites" },
    { "$sort": { "visites.formVersion": 1 } },
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 }, "data": { "$push": "$visites" } } }
])
```

I've realized that it has no sense to sort with a subfield, as the `visites` field is just an array of id's. Is it possible to populate them inside aggregate, so they can be sorted?

The results after nodejs population are these ones:

```
{
    "count": 50,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de4a",
            "formVersion": 4,
            "start": "2017-06-04T07:30:00.000Z",
            "end": "2017-06-04T08:30:00.000Z",
            "type": "assessor",
            "expedient": "58d46ffaf1c383862cf5de41",
            "user": "58d46ff8f1c383862cf5de3a",
            "__v": 0,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "lastModified": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.343Z",
            "created": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.330Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de49",
            "formVersion": 3,
            "start": "2017-06-03T07:30:00.000Z",
            "end": "2017-06-03T08:30:00.000Z",
            "type": "assessor",
            "expedient": "58d46ffaf1c383862cf5de41",
            "user": "58d46ff8f1c383862cf5de3a",
            "__v": 0,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "lastModified": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.341Z",
            "created": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.328Z"
        },
```

Comment: [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming two collections `coll1` and `coll2`:

```
> db.coll1.find()

{
 "_id": ObjectId("58eecf2a11b7af6f560666d8"),
  "otherFields": {

 },
 "visites": [
   "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de4a",
   "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de49"
  ]
}
> db.coll2.find()
{
  "_id": "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de4a",
  "formVersion": 4,
  "start": "2017-06-04T07:30:00.000Z",
  "end": "2017-06-04T08:30:00.000Z",
  "type": "assessor",
  "expedient": "58d46ffaf1c383862cf5de41",
  "user": "58d46ff8f1c383862cf5de3a",
  "__v": 0,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "lastModified": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.343Z",
  "created": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.330Z"
}
{
  "_id": "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de49",
  "formVersion": 3,
  "start": "2017-06-03T07:30:00.000Z",
  "end": "2017-06-03T08:30:00.000Z",
  "type": "assessor",
  "expedient": "58d46ffaf1c383862cf5de41",
  "user": "58d46ff8f1c383862cf5de3a",
  "__v": 0,
  "isDeleted": false,
  "lastModified": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.341Z",
  "created": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.328Z"
}
```

If you're looking to sort by e.g. the `formVersion` field, one possible aggregate pipeline solution could be:
db.coll1.aggregate([

```
// left outer join from coll2 to coll1
{$lookup:{
    from:"coll2",
    localField:"visites",
    foreignField:"_id",
    as:"data"
}},

// unwind the resulting array
{$unwind:"$data"},

// sort the unwinded documents using the formVersion field
{$sort:{"_id":1 ,"data.formVersion": 1}},

// collect the results into an array
{$group:{"_id":null, data:{$push:"$data"}}}
])
```

The result of the pipeline is:

```
 {
  "_id": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de49",
      "formVersion": 3,
      "start": "2017-06-03T07:30:00.000Z",
      "end": "2017-06-03T08:30:00.000Z",
      "type": "assessor",
      "expedient": "58d46ffaf1c383862cf5de41",
      "user": "58d46ff8f1c383862cf5de3a",
      "__v": 0,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "lastModified": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.341Z",
      "created": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.328Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "58d46ffbf1c383862cf5de4a",
      "formVersion": 4,
      "start": "2017-06-04T07:30:00.000Z",
      "end": "2017-06-04T08:30:00.000Z",
      "type": "assessor",
      "expedient": "58d46ffaf1c383862cf5de41",
      "user": "58d46ff8f1c383862cf5de3a",
      "__v": 0,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "lastModified": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.343Z",
      "created": "2017-03-24T01:01:47.330Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that as of MongoDB 3.4, there are certain limitations in the `$lookup` stage; such as the two collections must be in the same database, and the `from` parameter cannot be a sharded collection. For more details, please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/
Also please note that the last `$group` stage would result in a single document, which will be bound by MongoDB's 16 MB document size limit. If you prefer, you can remove the `$group` stage and iterate on the cursor returned by the `$sort` stage instead.

Comment: Thanks, haven't verified your answer, but definitively I've ended using `$lookup` as @Veeram suggested